# Valor do campo da busca não chega no jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário onde tem uma busca interna e uma paginação em Jquery e PHP. O resultado final é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está funcionando corretamente a paginação, porém quando digito o nome do usuário, o valor cheg nulo no jquery. Como posso pegar o valor digitado pelo jquery no campo de busca e implementar no código abaixo:

**Campo de busca:**

```
  <form class="" action="#!" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" name="Usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar por nome" id="usuario" aria-label="Buscar por nome">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
     <button type="submit" class="input-group-text" style="cursor: pointer"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <span id="conteudo"></span>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
    var qnt_result_pg = 10;
    var pagina = 1;
    var busca = $("#usuario").val();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        listar_usuario(pagina, qnt_result_pg, busca);
    });
    function listar_usuario(pagina, qnt_result_pg, busca){
    var dados = {
            pagina: pagina,
    busca: busca,
            qnt_result_pg: qnt_result_pg
        }
        $.post('listar-pagamentos-pendentes.php', dados , function(retorna){
            $("#conteudo").html(retorna);
        });
    }
</script>
```

**PHP (listar-pagamentos-pendentes.php)**

```
$pagina = $_POST['pagina'];
$qnt_result_pg = $_POST['qnt_result_pg'];
$busca = $_POST["busca"];
echo $metodos->listarPendentes($pagina,$qnt_result_pg,$busca);
```

Entendo que tenho que pegar o clique do botão da busca, mas não estou sabendo implementar no código acima sem impactar na paginação. Gostaria de ressaltar que o problema não está no PHP e sim no Jquery, pois não estou conseguindo pegar o valor digitado no campo de busca e jogar para dentro da página **listar-pagamentos-pendentes.php** onde faço a paginação.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma. Inclui o valor do POST em PHP dentro do Jquery. Fiquem à vontade em corrigirem:

```
var busca = "<?php echo $_POST["Usuario"]; ?>";
```